# Can someone tell me why I get this output?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, collatz

Ok, so I have a Collatz sequence length defined by the following code:

```
    private static int count = 0;

    private static int collatz(int n){
        count++;
        if(n > 1){
            if(n % 2 == 0){
                return collatz(n/2);
            }
            return collatz(3*n+1);
        }
        return count-1;
    }
```

Now, I checked the output (e.g. print(collatz(3000)) => 48) of different numbers to verify if the algorithm works correctly. I used [various sites](http://www.freemotion.nl/reken/collatz.php) to do this, yet one number refuses to work. And that number is exactly the solution of the 14th problem on ProjectEuler. How is this possible, that with every other number I get the right result (the correct chain length) while 837799 produces a different result: 58, instead of 524.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe that number was chosen very specifically because the sequence it generates contains large numbers that overflow a Java `int`?

Comment: did u try using long ?

Comment: Mat's right, use `long` and see.

Comment: I suspect that `collatz(n/2)` should be `collatz(n/2.0)`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - integer arithmetic is fine here. The division by 2 only happens for even numbers.

Comment: Mat and Ziyao are right. I traced through the program and the numbers get too big for `int` to handle. Change everything to a `long` and try again.

Comment: @TedHopp You are right :)

Comment: I'll use long. Thanks guys.

Comment: Note: there are a lot of smaller numbers that will land you in an infinite negative cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other pointed out in the comments, this is an overflow problem. You could have spotted this by printing the argument of the function call.

Change `int` to `long`, or even better, to be absolutely sure it does not overflow, use `BigInteger`:

```
private static int collatz(BigInteger n) {
    count++;
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0) {
        if (!n.testBit(0)) // even
            return collatz(n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));

        else
            return collatz(n.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3)).add(BigInteger.ONE));
    }
    return count - 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("res: " + collatz(BigInteger.valueOf(837799)));
}
```